# message passing and signaling in distributed system

Tags: java, video, distributed, message, apache-zookeeper

I have a distributed video analysis system, which is composed of:

```
1. feature extraction: generated lots of features(20+) from each frame of the video
2. multiple detectors(in different machine): 
  * Each of them will get a subset of feature
  * Each of them needs the features from multiple frames. 
  * Eg. Detector 1 needs feature 1-5 from 3 frames to start processing; Detector 2 needs feature 2-8 from 8 frames to start processing
```

My question is: how to do the communication between feature extraction block and multiple detectors, preferably in real-time? I have been looking at an event bus, but it's only for one process, will ZooKeeper in Hadoop be a better solution?

I am using Java. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: How much data is there in a feature? Like 8 bytes per feature? If you have really small data, there are many simple things you can do, like broadcast all features to all detectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you could consider using [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) message bus. There is a library with [Java bindings](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html).

> RabbitMQ is based on a proven
>   platform, offering exceptionally high
>   reliability, availability and
>   scalability along with good throughput
>   and latency performance that is
>   predictable and consistent. It has a
>   compact, easily maintainable code base
>   allowing rapid customisation and hot
>   deployment. There are extensive
>   facilities for management, monitoring,
>   control and debugging and it is
>   supported by a full range of
>   commercial support services and an
>   active community developing packages
>   that extend the core system.

Comment: The license is the Mozilla Public License, yes? If so, it should be a license quite permissible for corporate use.

Comment: Rabbit's blurb is not really truthful.  It is not highly available in the way most people expect -- queues distributed across multiple machines in order to withstand node failure.  Its clustering is designed to increase *speed under heavy load* but not make it more available-in-the-event-of-an-outage sense.

Comment: @Drew R - eh? How can something which is built to withstand node failure also not help make it more available in the event of an outage?

Comment: That must be a new feature. The clustering support wasn't able to tolerate node failure in at least 1.x, and I thought in early versions of 2.x. It was purely for increased throughput.